# How to show if 2 vectors are the same

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I've been given 2 lines in different forms

$L1$ is $$\frac{x-1}{4} = \frac{y-2}{3} = \frac{z-10}{5} $$

$L2$ is
$$x = -7-4t$$
$$y = -4-3t$$
$$z = -5t$$

I've converted $L2$ into its Cartesian form as follows
$$\frac{x+7}{-4} = \frac{y+4}{-3} = \frac{z}{-5} $$

The question is, how can I show that $L1$ is identical to $L2$?

So far I've managed to figure out that $(1,2,10)$ is a common point between them.  I've also been given the hint that both lines are parallel to $4i+3j+5k$. I'm having trouble understanding how to prove that these lines are parallel to that vector as well as how it was derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are indeed identical. We have

$$\frac{x+7}{-4}=\frac{y+4}{-3}=\frac{z}{-5}$$

Mutliplying by $-1$ we get:

$$\frac{x+7}{4}=\frac{y+4}3=\frac{z}{5}$$

Subtracting 2 we then get:

$$\frac{x-1}{4}=\frac{y-2}{3}=\frac{z-10}{5}$$

Which is exactly the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** While your idea to convert them to look like one another was a good idea, it is a bit easier to think about doing the other conversion. Once you have both lines in this form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_0\\y_0\\z_0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} a\\b\\c \end{bmatrix} t,$$

then the lines are parallel if the vectors attached to the $t$s are equal. The lines are *equal* if they have two points in common; the natural candidate points are the $(x_0,y_0,z_0)^T$ for both lines. Solve the system of equations to see if there is a choice of $t$ in one equation that gets you the initial point of the other, and vice versa.